# Subscribing to changes in siblings with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using inheritance to implmenet a reuseable forms app.
Expression parameter can be dependent on one or more other numeric/constant ot other expression parameters (the relation is many to many so heirarchy wont work here). Once all my dependent parameters evaluated them self (calcualted if expression or validated if user input) I can now calculate my self.

I'm looking for a way to subscribe to my siblings but the problem is that during creation the sibling does not neccasarily exists yet.

I set up a small example on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DvjQ/).

To see this *not working* in action lets change the values from the console

```
d.parameters()[0].value(10) // expecting parameter C to sum up to 20.
d.parameters()[2].value()   // Nothing (this should also update ont he screen).
d.parameters()[1].value(20) // expecting parameter C to sum up to 30.
d.parameters()[2].value()   // Still nothing.
```

So Ive tried sevral things but i think i'm barking up the wrong tree here.

- Fetching the parent using `ko.dataFor(document.body)` or
  fetching the object from the DOM using the same function.
- I've played around with `deferEvaluation` as you can see in the code
  to force KO to first create the parameters and then apply the
  binding. seems to do nothing.
- Tried creating a observableArray with the links to the params and a
  computed based on the array but the problom remain.

Appreciate any help here.

Bonus question, without losing focus from the main one, somehing I cant explain going on on line 73.

Comment: The KO computeds are just working fine. But your computed property `value` implementation is incomplete/wrong. Your `$.map` does not return the values you are not even calling your `value()` function... here is fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/yd6E2/ and a lots of `var` were missing in your fiddle which could lead to unexpected results and polluting the global scope...

Comment: Thats great man ! Thanks. You know why the `$.map` for `self.parameters` in `MyModelView` is not working ?